# Relation of $\int \frac{f}{g}$ and $\frac {\int f}{\int g}$

Tags: integration

I have two sequences of continuous functions $f_n,g_n$ on a compact space, e.g. $[0,1]^2 $.
I know that $f_n,g_n>0$, that $f_n,g_n$ converge pointwise to $0$ on $[0,1]^2$, and $f_n(x,y)/g_n(x,y)$ converges pointwise to $0$ if $x \neq 1$, and $\frac{f_n(x,y)}{g_n(x,y)} =1$ $\forall x=1$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Also we have that $\frac{f_n}{g_n}$ is monotone decreasing. Therefore by the monotone convergence theorem
$$\int \frac{f_n}{g_n} \rightarrow \int 0 =0.$$
However I am wondering if something can be said about
$$ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int f_n}{\int g_n}.$$
Is there something like an inverse Cauchy-Schwarze inequality giving something similar to 
$$ \int \frac{f}{g} \leq \frac{\int f}{\int g} \cdot C$$
or
$$ \int \frac{f}{g} \geq \frac{\int f}{\int g} \cdot C ,$$
for two functions $f>0,g>0$, where $C$ is a constant that does not depend on $f,g$, but possibly on the integration domain?

Thanks for all replies.
Carl

Comment: I don't think that those inequalities can exist as if you take $f$ and $g$ to be identically $1$, you get RHS as 1. But LHS depends on length of interval or area of surface. I am not sure but do you understand what I want to say?

Comment: Hölder's inquality yields $\frac{\int f }{\|g\|_p}\leq \|\frac{f}{g}\|_q$ where $\frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{q}=1$ ($1$ and $\infty$ are possible here). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty: I edited the question, because it should exclude cases as the one you mentioned. Actually an additional constant #depending on the interval size does not bother me for the application.

Comment: @Roland: Thx Roland. That already helps.  Following your hint with $p,q=2$ I arrive at $\frac{\int f}{\int g} = \frac{\Vert f \Vert_1}{\Vert g \Vert_1} \leq \frac{\Vert f \Vert_1}{\Vert g \Vert_2} \leq \Vert \frac{f}{g} \Vert_2.$, where I used that $\Vert - \Vert_1 \geq \Vert - \Vert_2$. Then this gives me for my application that $\frac{\int f_n}{\int g_n} \leq (\int (\frac{f_n}{g_n})^{2})^\frac{1}{2} \stackrel{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$, where the convergence of the RHS follows by the monotone convergence thm applied to $(\frac{f_n}{g_n})^{2}$ (+ cont. of $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$).

Comment: @CarlHeese: By Hölder, we have $\|g\|_1 \leq \|1\|_2 \|g\|_2$. If I am not mistaken, you're using the inequality the other way around.

Comment: @Roland: You are perfetctly right. I messed the inequality up. In any case, I found a solution to the problem now luckily. The solution is based on the specifics of the situation I am looking at. So I won't post it here, because it would be too specific.